# Scrolling function throws error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null"

Tags: javascript, html

My intention is to move to the another division by clicking the link button, it should make the page to scroll to reach my desired division but it is not happening. what wrong is in this JavaScript code.

```
var scrollY = 0;
var distance = 40;
var speed = 24;
function autoScroll(element) {
    var targetY = document.getElementById(element).offsetTop;   
    alert(element);
    var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
    var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
    var yPos = currentY + window.innerHeight;
    var animator = setTimeout('autoScroll(\' '+element+' \')', speed);
    if(yPos > bodyHeight) {
        clearTimeout(animator);
    } else {
        if(currentY < targetY - distance) {
            scrollY = currentY + distance;
            window.scroll(0, scrollY);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(animator);
        }
    } 

}
```

```
<h3 id = "main"> Main Heading </h3>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "autoScroll('div1');"> Box 1 </a> <br/>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "autoScroll('div2');"> Box 2 </a> <br/>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "autoScroll('div3');"> Box 3 </a> <br/>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "autoScroll('div4');"> Box 4 </a> <br/>
<div id = "div1" class = "content"> First Box </div>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "release('main');"> Go Back to Main </a>
<div id = "div2" class = "content"> Second Box </div>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "release('main');"> Go Back to Main </a>
<div id = "div3" class = "content"> Third Box </div>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "release('main');"> Go Back to Main </a>
<div id = "div4" class = "content"> Fourth Box </div>
<a href = "#"  onclick = "return false;" onmousedown = "release('main');"> Go Back to Main </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `offset()` is a function and `top` is a property.

```
var targetY = document.getElementById(element).offset().top;
```

this is reffering to the problem in your subject. The question is not make with the good practices of stackoverflow.

Comment: The error says that element is null. Are you passing the correct id?

Comment: No, there is a property called offsetTop to returns the distance of the current element. In my code, consider the target division top is '150', in this the scrolling happens based on the distance, value is '40' and the currentY is '0'. To reach the target div top, this code will be executed until "currentY < targetY - distance" condition gets false. currentY value will hop like 0, 40, 80, 120, thus the comparision like 0 < 110 (150-40), 40 < 110, 80 < 110, 120 <110 (false).  So it should execute for 4 times, but after the first execution itself it throws an error.

Comment: You can provide a jsfiddle? Or show us how do you call this function

Comment: Maybe your DOM is not complete loaded when you call the function. I make a local test and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code is working fine. I just removed the space from the element using trim() method.

```
function autoScroll(element) {
    var targetY = document.getElementById(element.trim()).offsetTop;   
    var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
    var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
    var yPos = currentY + window.innerHeight;
    var animator = setTimeout('autoScroll(\' '+element+' \')', speed);
```

Comment: Not really the most appropriate answer, using the timeout correctly would be a better fix : `var animator = setTimeout(function() {autoScroll(element)}, speed);`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNpxKv?editors=001